# How to add values automatically in excel every day

Tags: excel

Hello I would like to know if its possible to add values in already existing values every day. For example I have some vehicles in an excel spreadsheet and i want to add spesific values every day. The values are the same every day. A vehicle has 150km and tomorrow will have 200km. How i can make it update daily automatically? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will prove a sample of code which may help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, KMS As Long, AdditionalValue As Long
    Dim Vehicle As String
    Dim stDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To LastRow

                AdditionalValue = 50
                stDate = .Range("A" & i).Value
                Vehicle = .Range("B" & i).Value
                KMS = .Range("C" & i).Value

                Do Until stDate = Date

                    KMS = KMS + AdditionalValue
                    stDate = stDate + 1

                Loop

                .Range("D" & i).Value = KMS

            Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]